# Updated MikTex to 20.10 version recently, however, there are errors after compilation: ifpdf.sty error, Can be used only in preamble. \ProvidesPackage

Tags: miktex, texstudio

Even though everything is in correct place. In addition, the output PDF file top shows `ifpdf[2019/10/25 v3.4, ifpdf legacy package. Use Iftex instead]iftex`.

Before this updating while MikTex is 20.7 version, there is no error with this file.

Please help! Thanks.

Comment: Hi and welcome. Please provide the code that produces this error for anyone to investigate.

Comment: Did you remember to update MikTeX in both MikTeX user mode and MikTeX admin mode? Otherwise please show the log that produced this error (not a sniplet of the log, the full log, regading MikTeX we can decude a lot from this log)

Comment: Yes, I have updated in both MikTex user mode and admin mode. I even did several clean installations and the problem persists. Now I am a "private user" , user mode only and there is no improvement.  I pasted the log file below and highly appreciate your suggestions/comments.

Comment: The log file contains too many characters for posting here but it is linked at https://pastebin.com/WYWieE96. Thank you again.

Comment: Updated MikTex to version 20.11 and problems are still persistent and same. Any suggestions are welcomed. Thanks.

Comment: This problem has been resolved after MikTex has been updated to version 20.12, revtex has been updated to version 4.2, and use package [ifpdf].  Please close it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Easy, comments the lines between \else and \fi and add the command: \input iftex.sty in the file ifpdf.sty (normally available at C:\MiKTeX\tex\generic\iftex

For further details, see: https://www.mathwit.com/math/m2/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=43

Good luck!